# Avoid loading .Net Dlls in a C++/CLI project?

Tags: interop, c++-cli, unmanaged, managed

I have a project written in C++/CLI. Some of the types there are in managed code, and some are in completely native code. Let's say I have the produced DLL on a machine that dosen't have any version of the .Net framework installed, is there a way that another, native application will link with my "mixed-mode" Dll and use only the native types? I've noticed that the minute I add the "/clr" switch, my Dll automatically depends on several .Net Framework Dlls (mscorjit, mscoree etc.), and when I actually try to use the 100% native types defined in it, the application still tries to load those .Net Framework Dlls (even though I don't use the framework in that part of the code).
So, is it possible to avoid loading those Dlls in such case? (as I see it, the other option is to create another, native project, that will contain all of the native types, without the managed ones).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  When you load a mixed mode assembly (/clr), right after DllMain runs, the .cctor runs and initializes the framework, if it hasn't already been setup for the application.

Without this, there would be a big hit as soon as you called a function that required a managed API.  For details, see "[Initialization of Mixed Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173266.aspx)" on MSDN.

The best option would be to make your native API a separate DLL, and have the mixed mode assembly a separate project, so you can load it separately if required.